# JVM error in Apache JMeter 4.0

Tags: java, apache, jmeter, jvm

Apache JMeter 4.0 gives an error from an OS Process Sampler:

> "Could not create java virtual machine"

when running a "java -jar ..."

How can we solve this error?

Thank you

Comment: "Could not create java virtual machine" is the general error message. Look for the specific cause in the output.

Comment: JMeter does not give further details

Comment: JMeter gives detail in stderr: Unrecognized option: -jar runnable.jar (where "runnable.jar" is the .jar file to execute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put `java` as the "Command" and all the arguments like `-jar` and friends each on the separate line in the "Command parameters" section of the [OS Process Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) like:

[image: JMeter OS Process Sampler]

Example output would be

[image: JMeter -version output]

More information: [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter)

Comment: Thanks a lot. As you show in the first picture "-jar" and the .jar location must be in two separate parameters.